# How do I turn unity back on?

Tags: unity, upgrade, nautilus, partial-upgrade

My ubuntu 14.04 upgrade didn't work.  When I rebooted after it was done I had to choose between something called cinnamon and something called gnome fall back.  I don't like either.  I can't find unity to turn it back on. Also, I can't find nautilus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If other things are working, you can get back unity by installing the `ubuntu-desktop` package.

You can boot to gnome fallback, open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

After the installation, you will get the option to boot into Unity (I think it displays as "Ubuntu")